# AWS Batch executor with Airflow

Tags: airflow

I'm currently using airflow on Amazon Web services using EC2 instances. The big issue is that the average usage of the instances are about 2%...

I'd like to use a scalable architecture and creating instances only for the duration of the job and kill it. I saw on the roadmap that AWS BATCH was suppose to be an executor in 2017 but no new about that.

Do you know if it possible to use AWS BATCH as an executor for all airflow jobs ?

Regards,
Romain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there is a SequentialExecutor, a LocalExecutor, a DaskExecutor, a CeleryExecutor and a MesosExecutor. I heard they're working on AIRFLOW-1899 targeted for 2.0 to introduce a KubernetesExecutor. So, looking at Dask and Celery it doesn't seem they support a mode where their workers are created per task. Mesos might, Kubernetes should, but then you'd have to scale the clusters for the workers accordingly to account for turning off the nodes when un-needed.

We did a little work to get a cloud formation setup where celery workers scale out and in based on metrics from cloud-watch of the average cpu load across the tagged workers.

Answer (score 7):

There is no executor, but an operator is available from version 1.10. After you create an Execution Environment, Job Queue and Job Definition on AWS Batch, you can use the `AWSBatchOperator` to trigger Jobs.

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/operators/awsbatch_operator.py).

Comment: QQ Rafael -- When using the existing operator, would AWS Batch terminate EC2 instances anytime the queue is empty and there are no jobs to process?

Comment: Also, when you say there is no executor (but there is an operator) can you please elaborate on this difference in AF with respect to this question? (automatically terminating idling resources if not needed).

Comment: Batch can be setup so you don't have any EC2 instances running when the queue is empty, check the docs. 
The important difference here between executor and operator, is that you still need to run an Airflow server (webserver/scheduler/worker) somewhere, but the heavy lifting is done in Batch. If you want more details, reach out to the mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a custom Executor (*extended from [`BaseExecutor`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/executors/base_executor.py)*) capable of submitting and monitoring the AWS Batch jobs. Also may need to create a custom Docker image for the instances.

Answer (score 1):

I found this repository in my case is working quite well https://github.com/aelzeiny/airflow-aws-executors I'm using Batch jobs with FARGATE_SPOT with computation engine.

I'm just struggling with the logging on AWS CloudWatch and the return status in AWS batch but from Airflow perspective is working